# How can I make my JS check all lists in UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
<script>
function validateform() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
    var li_arr = document.getElementById("test-div").getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (textValue.indexOf(li_arr) != -1) {
        document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = 'Correct!';
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
    }
}
</script>
```

The textareabox is just a textarea where users can add their answer.

In my UL - LI in the test-div I have the answers that are correct.

If the answer in the textareabox matches one of the answers in the li it should say Correct!, if none of them is corrrect it should say incorrect!

but I can not get the javascript to work on running through the list.. it says:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: textValue is not defined`

it should though because I list the li's in li_arr.

```
<div id="test-div">
<ul>
    <li>loll</li>
    <li>lol</li>
    <li>ololol</li>
    <li>lolol</li>
</ul></div>
```

the textarebox is a simple textare

```
<textarea id="textareabox">
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We need your HTML. Also, why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML to go with your javascript please.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom the error is true.  nowhere in the example provided do you define the variable `textValue`, yet you use it in your if statement as if you had.

Comment: Is this better? I understand I should add the HTML but its a whole page in a WordPress theme.

Comment: Also `getElementsByTagName()` will return a node list. Notice getElement**s**  **`S`** not Element.

Comment: So then extract the relevant pieces until you can reproduce your problem. Don't be lazy and make people do the work for you—you'll find often that just isolating your problem is enough to figure it out without having to ask for help. The exception is pretty obvious in this case...start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume you want something like this ?

https://jsbin.com/libosupahu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
function validateform() {
var textarea = $('#myval').val();
var result = "no"; 

$("#test-ul li").each( function()                  
                           {
console.log($(this).text());

if ($(this).text() == textarea)
  {
   result = "yes";
  }

}
                           );
 console.log(result);
 if (result == "yes")
{
  $('#valid').text( "Correct!");
}
else
{

  $('#valid').text("Incorrect!");
}


}


$(document).ready(function()
             {

 $("#validate").click(function(){validateform();});
}
) ;
`
```

Comment: I don't get why you're getting downvoted this is exactly what I want! I got it working as well!! thank you so much!! been working on this for 2 days.